# FragmentActivity calls onCreate after coming back from another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

So, I need some code to be executed only once when `FragmentActivity` is created. I was method thining that `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is only called first time when FragmentActivity comes to flow. But, then from that FragmentActivity I go into another and after coming back from that second one, `onCreate` gets called again. I was looking on FragmentActivity cycle and that's not clear for me. Is there method that only gets invoked at very beginning and not after coming back on that activity any more?

Comment: Could you verify that `FragmentActivity.onDestroy` is not called?

Comment: @curtisLoew - huh, for some reason it got destroyed after calling another `FragmentActivity`. Do you know why? Is it maybe because all I have are many `FragmentActivities` that use the same `SectionsPagerAdapter` ?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I would just be speculating. Pay attention to second paragraph of the [Activity lifecycle docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), it might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did help. I'm just examining if the savedInstanceState is null and that does the work. You should write this as answer, so you could get some points for help :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! I do like imaginary interwebs points, so I posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you verify that `FragmentActivity.onDestroy` is not called? If it does get called, maybe the [second paragraph of the of the Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) could help you understand what's going on.